# Linking to Wikipedia abstracts (the way Google Earth does it)

Tags: wikipedia, google-earth

I'm embedding Wikipedia pages in my app, and I'd like to show the same simplified abstract that Google Earth shows.  (It gives the first several paragraphs and a link to the full content, without any serious layout.)

I know about the printable=true option, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) : you can grab a "text" version of any article. Afterwards, it is up to you to extract the summary.

Another option is just to request the page in *raw* format:

`Raw (Wikitext) page processing: sending a action=raw or a action=raw&templates=expand GET request to index.php will give the unprocessed wikitext source code of a page.`

E.g.

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page?action=raw`

Of course you'll need to do a bit a scraping.  Going through the API might prove more efficient as you have better control of what you can *pull* from the database directly (wikitext if you wish).

Comment: I was hoping for a magic keyword (like printable)...but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Wikipedia API? Mediawiki (and so Wikipedia) has a feature-rich and flexible API which is documented on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mediawiki API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) with action=query and  prop=revisions to fetch a given **revision** , remove the wikitext ( images, infoboxes) and extract the content of the first sentence.